# Record videos at higher FPS using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I bought a camera that, as per the specs, can record up to 100 fps.

I'm trying to record video at 100 fps using OpenCV, but when I pass the parameter into the VideoWriter method it doesn't output what I expect.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
result = cv2.VideoWriter('testVide.avi',  cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG'), 10, size)

while(True):
    i+=1
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        result.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        break
    else:
        break
```

If I pass 100 into the function, I would expect it to record 100 frames every second and then give me the ability to play the video in slow motion, however the output video plays like a fast forwarded version of the previous example. When I right click and look at the video properties, the frames per second is still around 10.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I record 100 fps and play back in slow motion?

Comment: what happens when you print `cap`?

Comment: when you feed with 100 fps and writer is parametrized for 100 fps then your video will play in normal speed. If you feed with < 100 fps and the writer is parametrized for 100 fps then your video will play fast forward. If you feed 100 fps and the writer is parametrized for < 100 fps then the video will play in slow motion. In your case, very likely the writer isnt fast enough, so you dont actually reach the 100 fps capturing (because of the writer and the imshow and the waitkey will block the capturing when needing more than 10 ms).

Comment: for such high frame rates (and even for lower frame rates tbh.) you might want to 1. separate capturing and writing and rendering by using multiple threads. 2. add a large buffer in between so that even if writer is slower than capturing, you can record a nice amount of data without losing frames.

Comment: ok sorry, you parametrized the writer to 10 fps, which is ok if you want a slow motion video file (assuming you feed 100 fps). In the end it means that your capturing doesnt even reach the 10 fps. Please check the processing time of result.write + imshow + waitKey, which might be > 100 ms if you are on a slow device. And please check the parametrized fps of the VideoCapture with cap.get. It could be possible, that the opencv interface doesnt allow you to use the full 100 fps of the camera (either by default or at all). What kind of camera are you using? Does it have its own API?

Comment: `waitKey(1)` will slow the entire loop down. try `pollKey()`, that'll save you at least a millisecond, if not an entire scheduler time slice. -- next: you need **hardware encoding**. -- then: **do not use OpenCV AT ALL!**. it's for computer vision, not for recording and compressing video. use ffmpeg or VLC or whatever.

Comment: The reason I'm using OpenCV is because the video recording and processing all forms part of a Python script. Sensor data comes in, starts recording video, and then crops video when another sensor input arrives. Since it's so closely married to the script I thought this would be a good library for the video recording part

Comment: @Micka, what I'm trying to do is record a golf swing at high speed. Basically I have a sensor that detects when the ball is hit and communicates that via serial to the script. I want to have a high FPS video so that I can play it in slow motion and improve the golf swing. The camera I recorded says that it can capture data at 100fps (not sure I fully understand what this means), is there a better option besides OpenCV?

Comment: perform some experiment: 1. remove all the imshow and waitKey and videowriter stuff. 2. just capture and write the images to a list (in memory). 3. after x seconds of capturing, quit the loop and write all the images from the list to files (.jpg or .png images). 4. point the camera to a digital stopwatch. 5. run that program. 6. when finished, check the achieved frames per second by comparing the number of images per second of the watch visible in the images. That's a way to check the achieved fps you can get with those devices (camera and pc) with opencv without adjusting parameters.